# Django queryset with prefetch or not?

Tags: python, django

I have such models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    …
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=‘cat’)
    name = models.CharField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to create queryset which will select all products with price >= 100 grouped by categories. Afterwards I need to get count of products in each category.

I did

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(product__price__gte = 100)
```

This queryset gave me all categories which contain product with price >= 100. But how can I get count of products in it and products themseves? Maybe I need to use a prefetch_related, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using`Count` with conditional aggregation from `django`.

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(product__price__gte = 100).\
annotate(count_of_products=Count('products', filter=Q(product__price__gte = 100)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel glad that it helped. You can vote up if liked thanks.